# Query to get output for stock

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need output through query as per given below points

1. there is stock table contains all items with multiple salemrp
2. I need those records whose stock is present in multiple salemrp, but if there is only one salemrp for an item, I require also those records.

My query is as follows, please help me, how to manipulate this query.

```
SELECT
    itemid,
    grpid,
    (SELECT
        itemname
        FROM sap_itemmASter
        WHERE itemid=sap_stockmASter.itemid )AS itemname, 
    (SELECT grpname
        FROM sap_grpmASter
        WHERE grpid=sap_stockmASter.grpid) AS grpname,
    (SELECT partno
        FROM sap_itemmASter
        WHERE itemid=sap_stockmASter.itemid) AS partno,
    salemrp,
    (SELECT brANDname
        FROM sap_brANDmASter
        WHERE brANDid IN (SELECT brANDid
                            FROM sap_itemmASter
                            WHERE itemid=sap_stockmASter.itemid)) AS catname,
    (laneno + ' - ' + rackno) AS locno,
    isnull(SUM(stkqty),0) AS balqty,
    (SELECT top 1 (laneno + ' - ' + rackno)
        FROM sap_stockloc
        WHERE itemid=sap_stockmASter.itemid) AS storeloc
FROM sap_stockmASter
WHERE laneno!=''
AND itemid>0 
AND grpid IN (SELECT grpid
                FROM sap_grpmASter
                WHERE isactive=1
                AND isdel=1)
AND itemid IN (SELECT itemid 
                FROM sap_itemmASter
                WHERE isdel=1
                AND isactive=1
                AND laneno=sap_stockmASter.laneno
                AND rackno=sap_stockmASter.rackno) 
AND grpid=37
GROUP BY itemid,grpid,laneno,rackno,salemrp
ORDER BY itemname
```

**More information:**

```
Item Name   SaleMrp Qty 
ABC         158.00  48  
ABC         165.00  -11 
ABC         170.00  5
```

In this I want to not display negative stock, but

```
XYZ         125.00 0
```

(I need this record as well, beacause it has only one mrp)

```
PQR         100.00  -5
```

(I need this record as well, beacause it has only one mrp)

Comment: You should start using join's instead of subqueries in the select. That'll help you tremendously.

Comment: I tried with adding having sum(stkqty)>=0, but it not works.

Comment: @Allan S. Hansen, as I am not friendly with joins, can you help it into the same.

Comment: Much better to show a sample data and your expected output than to analyze that query like a blind.

Comment: @Shail.. please edit the question and format the output with column name, its pretty confusing how many rows and what value is for which column

Comment: Item Name  SaleMrp           Qty

ABC                       158.00           48 
ABC                       165.00          -11 
ABC                      170.00            5 

In this I want to not display negative stock, but

XYZ                      125.00           0 
(I need this record as well, beacause it has only one mrp)

PQR 100.00 -5 
(I need this record as well, beacause it has only one mrp)